# Open cart edit checkout functionality

Tags: opencart

I am new to this Opencart. I want to add some functionality in my open cart site. I want to create a pdf file with some text and order number after the check out process. I know it's possible to edit the check out model and controller files. But have a doubt that is it lose when i upgrade the opencart? If so is there is any other solution for this requirement?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in checkout/order.php model, which will handle the pdf generation operations. Then before upgrading, you can save the pdf generator function to another file to keep it.

I can recommend http://dompdf.github.com/ as  html to pdf generator.